# Exporting a partial scene or single object in Spline Design

Tags: 3d, spline, react-three-fiber

Is it only possible to export the whole scene in [spline.design](https://spline.design)?

I'm trying to export a single object or parts of the scene, similar to how any Frame can be exported in Figma.

Tried out all the available functionalities in the tool and checked the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible as of today; even removing all items from a spline scene will always generate a set of groups plus a camera when exporting. The following picture depicts the simplest hierarchy I managed to export.

[image: exported scene]

The workflow I follow when working with spline scenes and threejs is:

1. export the spline gltf scene
2. import to blender
3. select the object you would like to export
4. file > export > gltf and choose "selected objects" (see screenshot)
5. repeat for each object

[image: exporting one single object in blender]